# How to rename a project in SonarQube 5.1?

Tags: sonarqube-5.0

I can't find how to rename a project in SonarQube 5.1.

Once created, how one can change project name, key, branch, from the web dashboard?

[SonarQube's](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration) documentation doesn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to "update the project key" (I always think that the Sonar terminology here isn't very helpful)

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Settings#ProjectSettings-UpdatingProjectKey

and then re-run the analysis (with the new project key, so having updated your sonar-project.properties or build.xml or pom.xml, etc)

Comment: I'll give it a try. Documentation is not up-to-date. It's in `Settings > Update key` now and not `Configuration > Update key`.

Comment: BTW: it only updates the technical key, the name shown on the UI isn't affected. I changed that it in the DB, too.

Comment: What did you change in the DB to update UI display name?

Comment: In 7.x I found that updating the key and running the analysis causes the name to be updated automatically (for a Maven project)

Answer (score 22):

In SonarQube 5.1 the project name can't be changed from the web dashboard (Probably it will not be possible in the future as well).

I configure my SonarQube projects `sonar-project.properties` where I only have to change this line:

```
sonar.projectName=MyNewProjectName
```

Rerun the analysis to see the result in the web dashboard.

Comment: In SonarQube 6.5 you can update your project key by switching to your project and then "Administration" -> "Update key".
But the project name is still unchangeable as far as I know.

Comment: Why is it not possible in the future?

Comment: Which 'file' are you configuring here? Otherwise this answer is useless.

Comment: Updating just the `sonar.projectKey` did not work for me to update the name on the dashboard, but also updating `sonar.projectName` did [Version 6.7.7 (build 38951)]. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

To change the projet name in UI run this SQL query :

```
UPDATE sonar.projects
SET  name = 'NEW_PROJECT_NAME',
long_name = 'NEW_PROJECT_NAME'
WHERE kee = 'PROJECT_KEY'
```

Comment: In my SonarQube 7.8 database (SQL Server), the `projects` table was a member of the `dbo` schema, not the `sonar` schema.  But other than that, the update statement is correct and it worked for me.

Comment: long_name is not used anymore in last versions of SonarQube

Answer (score 6):

If you are using jenkins and your sonar build is a post build step. You may add the property mentioned by @adrianko to your goals.

```
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN -Dsonar.projectName="YOUR PROJECT NAME"
```

Answer (score 4):

In SonarQube 8.6 (PostgreSQL),  execute SQL

```
UPDATE projects
SET name = 'NEW_PROJECT_NAME'
WHERE kee = 'PROJECT_KEY';

UPDATE components
SET "name" = 'NEW_PROJECT_NAME',
  long_name = 'NEW_PROJECT_NAME'
WHERE kee = 'PROJECT_KEY';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ChangeProjectName
    @CaseSensitiveProjectKeyToChange VARCHAR(300),
    @NewProjectName VARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.projects WHERE kee = @CaseSensitiveProjectKeyToChange and scope = 'PRJ') > 1
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Operation would affect more than one record, cancelling for safety.', 16, 1)
END

UPDATE 
    dbo.projects
SET 
    name = @NewProjectName,
    long_name = @NewProjectName 
WHERE 
    kee = @CaseSensitiveProjectKeyToChange and
    scope = 'PRJ'   
END
GO
```

Sample Usage `usp_ChangeProjectName2 '<project key>', '<new name>'`

Answer (score 1):

Just add or edit `gradle.properties` file as below:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_191

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

systemProp.sonar.host.url=https://abc.xyz.com

#----- Token generated from an account with 'publish analysis' permission
systemProp.sonar.login=your token goes here

systemProp.sonar.projectName=ProjectName
```

Please change the path of JDK as per your system configuration, sonarqube server url, access token and finally the name of project that you want to give. By default in android studio project name is `app`

Just let me know if anybody face any problem while integration of sonarqube.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the way but it did not work for me . At last my bamboo server gave me some hint .
Instead of using projectName pror you can use "/n:" key..
i.e /n:"your project name".

Comment: This was what worked for me. I updated the project key in the GUI, then ran SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe with `/k:"My New Key" /n:"My New Key"` (assuming you want the key to be the project name)

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to rename the project in the web frontend (tested with Sonarqube V 9.3).

But you can change the project name by running the sonar scanner commandline interface locally and passing the new project name (also the sonar token and the project key) as parameter
(If sonar-scanner is started in the same directory in which **sonar-project.properties** is located, the properties are also read from this file):

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectName="enter_new_projectname_here“ -Dsonar.login="your_sonar_token“ -Dsonar.projectKey="your_project_key“
```

On macOS the sonar scanner can be installed with **homebrew**:

```
brew install sonar-scanner
```

For other platform see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli

Answer (score 0):

In our case, when we changed `-Dsonar.projectName` and ran the analysis on developers' branches, nothing changed.
Until we ran analysis on the **main** (master) branch -> then project name was automatically changed