# How to rename projects in Sonar Qube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a few projects which use pom.xmls to run the sonar analysis. Their names are:

Myproject1
Myproject2
Myproject3
Myproject4

I want to rename them on the sonar dashboard:

MyprojectA
MyprojectB
MyprojectC
MyprojectD

whats the simplest way to achieve this? I know that we can update the key, and then on-board the project with the desired name. Is it possible for me to use the same key and update the project display name?

P.S: I use sonarqube version 6.1

Comment: Update your SonarQube instance to the LTS version and have also a look at the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511849/how-to-rename-a-project-in-sonarqube-5-1) SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to eventually change the project name in the settings.xml file. This contained my sonar.projectname and sonar.projectkey. Then, I had to onboard the app on the sonar dashboard with the new details and run the analysis. However, i still feel that a simple renaming feature could have been easy. 
Since it is more of an enterprise version of sonar we are not allowed to upgrade the sonar version immediately.