# How to change the display name of a project on SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I already changed the key, but the displayed Name stayed the same. How can I change that one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a project in SonarQube 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511849/how-to-rename-a-project-in-sonarqube-5-1)

Comment: It's the same question, I just have hope that there is a different answer for SonarQube 7.0 in 2018 than for SonarQube 5.1 in 2015.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a `sonar-project.properties` file for your project, the name is specified thanks to the `sonar.projectName=...` property in that file.

If you are on a Maven project, this value comes from the the project name provided inside the root POM file.

Otherwise, you can set the name on the command line when running the analysis, usually with the `-Dsonar.projectName=...` argument.

Comment: Yes, adding `-Dsonar.projectName=...` changes project name whenever you add it (tested on CE)